# PHP Zend Framework Application needs index.php in URL to operate on CENTOS

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The application is only working when I add "index.php" to the end of the URL. I am using CENTOS. How do I remove this, so I can for example go to `http://server/admin/dashboard` instead of `http://server/admin/index.php/dashboard`. Here is my htaccess file:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check your apache conf if "allowOverride" is set to "all"

Comment: I checked and it is set to allowoverride all

Comment: may be missing "." before htaccess ? :-) .htaccess

Comment: If you go to `http://server/admin/dashboard` do you get a 404 page? If so your htaccess is not being used.

Comment: Yes I get a 404 page. However, if i go to http://server/admin/index.php/dashboard it works. Is there a setting within CENTOS apache that tells them not to use subdirectory htaccess. Theres a generic htaccess within the root apache public folder

Comment: AllowOverride is the setting, but it can be in several places. If you've already checked the main Apache config check the vhost for that site

Comment: Your rewrite module seems to be NOT working.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use, I got it from [Rob Allen](http://akrabat.com/) if I remember correctly:

```
//index.php
<?php
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = str_replace('index.php', '', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
//rest of index.php
```

There are other ways to do this, this is just the one I chose.

Comment: This doesn't work. I placed it at the top of my index.php page, before running the application.